# Autocomplete function in textarea with Dropdown suggestions for angular2 like typeahead

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, textarea

Looking for api on **autocomplete textarea like Dropdown suggestions** (mention users after typing @, hashtag support, keywords... ) for **angular2** like [smart-area](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smart-area) searching it for long time. Inside my textarea

```
<textarea class="comment-input" i18n-placeholder="leave a comment placeholder|leave a comment field placeholder text" placeholder="leave a comment" #commentInput
          (keyup.enter)="addComment()"
          (blur)="notifyUnsavedComment()"
          (input)="adjustHeightForCommentInput()"></textarea>
```

**Is there any api typedef available for Dropdown suggestions in textarea**. Any help would be great.

Comment: You can use jQuery UI for getting auto complete results. It's simple and easy to handle.

Comment: Its like autosuggestion dropdown (i.e '@name '@place ) inside textarea between some strings in typescript angular2...

Comment: Get suggestions using jqueryUI and write code to show inside text area